# How to match multiple json with multiple value in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have three json and wish to combine three of them to it respective value.

```
jsonlistA = { "header1": "Hello World1", "header2": "Hello World2", "header3": "Hello World3"}

jsonlistB = { "condition1": "halo1", "condition2": "halo2", "condition3": "halo3"}

jsonlistC = { "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2", "parameter3": "hi3"}
```

**What i want to achieve**

I want it to pair json list a,b,c with three value from three different list. For example, header1,condition1, parameter1 should be one list eg.

```
jsonCombineA = { "header1": "Hello World1", "condition1": "halo1","parameter1": "hi1"}
```

So when I print the json to string it should be `HelloWorld1 halo1 hi1`.

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work no matter if you change the order of the data inside the dictionary:

```
import re

jsonlistA = {"header1": "Hello World1",
             "header2": "Hello World2",
             "header3": "Hello World3"}
jsonlistB = {"condition1": "halo1",
             "condition2": "halo2",
             "condition3": "halo3"}
jsonlistC = {"parameter1": "hi1",
             "parameter2": "hi2",
             "parameter3": "hi3"}

data = []
for i, j in jsonlistA.items():
    number = re.search(r'[\d]+$', i)
    if number:
        number = number.group()
        key1, key2 = f"condition{number}", f"parameter{number}"
        data.append({i: j, key1: jsonlistB[key1], key2: jsonlistC[key2]})

[{'header1': 'Hello World1', 'condition1': 'halo1', 'parameter1': 'hi1'},
 {'header2': 'Hello World2', 'condition2': 'halo2', 'parameter2': 'hi2'},
 {'header3': 'Hello World3', 'condition3': 'halo3', 'parameter3': 'hi3'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for zip method

```py
a = b = c = range(20)
list(zip(a, b, c))
```

in your case just to take values from dict eg.

```py
a = jsonlistA.values()
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `zip`

By using `zip` on the keys of the list, it return this

```
('header1', 'condition1', 'parameter1')
('header2', 'condition2', 'parameter2')
('header3', 'condition3', 'parameter3')
```

Now we can have the desired output with

```
jsonlistA = { "header1": "Hello World1", "header2": "Hello World2", "header3": "Hello World3"}
jsonlistB = { "condition1": "halo1", "condition2": "halo2", "condition3": "halo3"}
jsonlistC = { "parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2", "parameter3": "hi3"}

for keys in zip(jsonlistA.keys(), jsonlistB.keys(), jsonlistC.keys()):
    print(f"{jsonlistA[keys[0]]} {jsonlistB[keys[1]]} {jsonlistC[keys[2]]}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` `dict.items` objects of each dict and use a dict constructor in a list comprehension:

```
jsonCombineA, jsonCombineB, jsonCombineC = [dict(tpl) for tpl in zip(jsonlistA.items(), jsonlistB.items(), jsonlistC.items())]
```

Output:

```
print(jsonCombineA)  # {'header1': 'Hello World1', 'condition1': 'halo1', 'parameter1': 'hi1'}
print(jsonCombineB)  # {'header2': 'Hello World2', 'condition2': 'halo2', 'parameter2': 'hi2'}
print(jsonCombineC)  # {'header3': 'Hello World3', 'condition3': 'halo3', 'parameter3': 'hi3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```py
jsonlistA = {"header1": "Hello World1", "header2": "Hello World2", "header3": "Hello World3"}
jsonlistB = {"condition1": "halo1", "condition2": "halo2", "condition3": "halo3"}
jsonlistC = {"parameter1": "hi1", "parameter2": "hi2", "parameter3": "hi3"}

jsonCombine = []
for data in zip(jsonlistA.items(), jsonlistB.items(), jsonlistC.items()):
    jsonCombine.append({i[0]: i[1] for i in data})
jsonCombineA = jsonCombine[0]
jsonCombineB = jsonCombine[1]
jsonCombineC = jsonCombine[2]
```

By the way, these are not "JSON lists", they are called `dict`.